# Heavy thrown implement for Invoker

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization, implements

I have this idea of a hybrid Fighter|Invoker, using Cleave and Deft Hurler to throw Divine Bolts.
Deft Hurler (Dr 368) lets you use a ranged basic attack after Cleave:

> Cleave: You can forgo dealing damage to the adjacent enemy to instead make a **ranged basic attack with a heavy thrown weapon** against one creature other than the target of your cleave. This ranged basic attack does not provoke opportunity attacks.

RAW, implement powers used with weapon implements still count as "with a weapon".

Power of Skill (DP) turns Divine Bolts into a basic attack:

> You can use any power you have that is associated with this feat as a basic attack. (Divine Bolts is listed)

**Now I just need a heavy thrown weapon with the highest damage that is usable as an implement by an Invoker.**
Bonus points if it is possible without a multiclass feat, as I want to use Seeker MC in paragon to get Primal Eye.

---

If it matters:
Str 17, Con 12, Dex 13, Int 8, Wis  16, Cha 8
Goliath (but any Str/Wis race will do)

Comment: Any material published by WotC is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your stats, it will take either 3 feats or 2 feats and an enchantment.

The first two feats are spent on getting Heavy Blade implements. This is exclusively available to arcane multiclasses, and the only one you qualify for is Binding Initiate [Dragon 402] (the others all need Int or Cha). This allows you to take Arcane Implement Proficiency (Heavy Blade) [Arcane Power].

The third feat would be on Weapon Proficiency (Drow Long Knife) [Eberron Player's Guide], which is not a very good weapon, but it is a Heavy Blade with Heavy Thrown, and it leaves your weapon enchantment open for something like elemental optimization. The alternative is to use the Farbond Spellblade [Adventurer's Vault 2] enchantment to give a different heavy blade (I recommend longsword, falchion, or fullblade) the Heavy Thrown keyword.

However, looking at the wording of the feats you are using, I do feel I need to point out that Deft Hurler Cleave specifically allows you to make a Ranged Basic Attack against **one** creature, so you could not target multiple enemies with Divine Bolts.

Comment: The updated Implement rules make Arcane Implement Proficiency unnecessary.

Comment: Which updated rules? The update to the implement rules made it so that they aren't specific to a class, but you still need to get the implement proficiency, which Binding Initiate doesn't give (Warlocks only have Rods and Wands). I guess you could use a Drow Long Knife Pact Blade, but that sounds like a fundamentally worse option than a Farbond Spellblade Longsword (both cost a feat and an enchantment)

Comment: sorry, you were right, I was wrong